# How can I fix the error : Multi-Part ID when update a field of @tempTable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, merge, sql-merge

I want to compare @tempTable with tableA, if matched then update FieldValue of @tempTable equal to id of tableA; if not matched then insert values ,and get the id of tableA to update FieldValue of @tempTable.

The following is my SQL query:

```
create table [dbo].[TableA]([Id] int Indentity(1,1),[Data] [sql_variant] NULL)

declare @tempTable table (FieldValue nvarchar(1000),FieldType nvarchar(1000))
insert @tempTable values ('some content','A Type') 

merge
    tableA
using (
    select 
        FieldValue
    from
        @tempTable
) x
on tableA.[Data] = x.FieldValue
when not matched then  
    insert values (x.FieldValue)
when matched then   
    update set x.FieldValue = tableA.[Id] ;
```

The following is the error message:

> Unable to tie the Multi-Part ID "x.FieldValue".

The error looks like it's different data type between x.FieldValue and tableA.id, so I adjust them to the same data type, but it's still not work, and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: To add to Schnugo's response - the table you are updating is tableA. You cannot update columns in x (which is @tempTable).

Comment: Thanks, I fixed my question and separated the writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following can achieve the results I want.

```
merge
  tableA
using (
  select 
    FieldValue
  from
    @tempTable
) x
on tableA.[Data] = x.FieldValue
when not matched then
  insert values (x.FieldValue);

update @tempTable
set t.FieldValue = i.[Id]
from @tempTable t
  join TableA i ON i.[Data] = t.FieldValue

select * from @tempTable
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? Your **target table is `tableA`**, your **source table is the x-aliased sub-query**.

Next time please try to create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I had to modify your code slightly, but you will get the ghist:

```
declare @TableA TABLE([Id] int,[Data] [sql_variant] NULL)

declare @tempTable table (FieldValue nvarchar(1000),FieldType nvarchar(1000))
insert @tempTable values ('some content','A Type'); 

merge
    @tableA a
using (
    select 
        FieldValue
    from
        @tempTable
) x
on a.[Data] = x.FieldValue
when matched then   
    update set a.id = x.FieldValue; --fields swapped, probably not really your intention...
```

**The point is:** Your code tries to update a field of your **source** table. The general idea of `MERGE` is

- We target one table where we want to insert/update/delete some records.
- We use a second set with the data we want to compare and use for these operations
- We find rows **within the source** which are missing in the target -> `INSERT`
- We find rows **within the source** which are existing in the target -> `UPDATE`
- We find rows **whithin the target** which are missing in the source -> `DELETE`

Saying this, I doubt, that the code above would need `MERGE` at all...